# Strings in downloadfile weird symbols

Tags: java, stream, vaadin

I've got a String array that contains the content for a downloadable file. I am converting it to a Stream for the download but there are some random values in the downloadfile. I don't know if it is due to the encoding and if yes, how can I change it?

```
var downloadButton = new DownloadLink(btn, "test.csv", () -> {
try {
   ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
   for (int i = 0; i < downloadContent.size(); i++) {
    objectOutputStream.writeUTF(downloadContent.get(i));
   }
objectOutputStream.flush();
objectOutputStream.close();
byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(byteArrayInputStream);

objectInputStream.close();

return new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
```

This is the DownloadLink class.

```
public class DownloadLink extends Anchor {
    public DownloadLink(Button button, String fileName, InputStreamFactory fileProvider) {
        super(new StreamResource(fileName, fileProvider), "");
        getElement().setAttribute("download", fileName);
        add(button);
        getStyle().set("display", "contents");
    }
}
```

[this is the output file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jj9Ix.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking
a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You know if you use `writeUTF` you need to complement that with `readUTF` ..?

Comment: (`writeUTF` writes in a special format and has to be read with `readUTF`)

Comment: I tried different write functions (writeBytes and writeObject) and they all had the same issue

Comment: If i had to guess, the whole problem rises from using all that serialization stuff? Do you want to create a CSV file or something, that one would be able to read using java serialization?

Comment: I too am wondering why `downloadContent` (which appears to be `List<String>`) is getting connected with `ObjectOutputStream`? It surely should be written just a strings in the normal way with a `PrintWriter`?

Comment: I had a fileWriter before where I wrote into a file on my desktop but now I had to switch to a download and I had the downloadLink class as an example from someone and tried to adapt to it by writing my content into a byte array that can then be used by the downloadLink

Comment: Well IS `downloadContent` a list of strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ObjectOutputStream` is part of the Java serialization system. In addition to the data itself, it also includes metadata about the original Java types and such. It's only intended for writing data that will later be read back using `ObjectInputStream`.

To create a file for others to download, you could instead use a `PrintWriter` that wraps the original output stream. On the other hand, you're using the output stream to create a `byte[]` which means that a more straightforward, but slightly less efficient, way would be to create a concatenated string from all the array elements and then use `getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` on it to directly get a byte array.